# Get the types instead the tokens of nodes (XML/XPath)

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have this XML-Database:

```
<database>
    <event>
        <location> abc </location>
    </event>
    <event>
        <location> abc </location>
    </event>
    <event>
        <location> abc </location>
    </event>
    <event>
        <location> def </location>
    </event>
    <event>
        <location> def </location>
    </event>
<database>
```

And I tried to get this output with XPath:

```
abc
def
```

The types of the location node.

If I use

```
//location
```

the output would be the tokens:

```
abc
abc
abc
def
def
```

Is this even possible with XPath? I tried it, but didn't find any solution.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "types" and "tokens" here, you seem to be using the words with an unconventional meaning.

Comment: @MichaelKay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction#Occurrences

Comment: Unfortunately both "type" and "token" have different meanings in the XPath language.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping in strict XPath 1.0 can be done with this expression:

```
/database
    /event
        /location[
            not(. = ../preceding-sibling::event/location)
        ]
```

**Note**: This has quadratic complexity. In small documents, you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `distinct-values(//location)`

Comment: It's important to mention that this only works with XPath-2.0.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this.
I get this error: 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'distinct-values(//location)' is not a valid XPath expression.
  showResult 
  xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: Is there any good reason you can't use an XPath 2.0 processor? Even in the Javascript world, XPath 2.0 processors exist.